# How can I parse any type of date in java?

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have an xml. Which return some element. One of the element is date and the output format is `2014-06-02T00:00:00.000+07:00`. Now I want to insert this time into access database using java.But I can't parse the xml date format into java. So I can't insert the date into access. How can I parse `2014-06-02T00:00:00.000+07:00` in java eclipse?

Comment: Google for Java date parsing. You will find SimpleDateFormat

Comment: why is your title different to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.), with the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX".